# Как записать файл в sd карту?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что я использую [библиотеку](https://github.com/Coolerfall/Android-HttpDownloadManager) для загрузки файлов. По умолчанию все загруженные файлы сохраняет в папку `Downloads` внутренней памяти телефона. Везде говорится что можно записать файлы в `SD-карту` таким способом:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
```

Да и в `README` тоже об этом пишет:

```
.destinationFilePath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator)
```

Но как бы это не менял, все равно загруженные файлы записывает во внутреннюю память. Только уже не в `Downloads`, а в корневую.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Глупая идея, но ты разрешения прописал в манифесте?

Comment: Да, конечно....

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано вот что, для `destinationFilePath` нужно задавать путь включая имя файла:

```
String destPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.apk";
```

Если имя файла не хочется задавать, надо использовать другой метод:

```
destinationDirectory(String directory)
```

Comment: Это тоже пробовал. Создается все равно во внутренней папке

Comment: Тогда пишите баг автору библиотеки.